# Как правильно выложить многостраничный сайт в сеть

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сделал многостраничный сайт и сейчас в тупике как правильно его выложить в сеть, чтобы была оптимальная прогрузка страниц. Сайт сделан на чистом HTML/CSS/JS. Много фотографий. У меня есть два варианта: 1)разместить весь сайт в одном каталоге и на одном домене (то есть будут несколько html страниц с перелинковкой друг а друга в меню навигации), но я не уверен, что это оптимизирует скорость загрузки сайта. 2)создать несколько каталогов на нескольких поддоменах с одним html файлом для каждой страницы, не уверен что так правильно. Просьба подсказать какой вариант лучше. Если есть более оптимальные способы - буду рад выслушать.

Comment: Среднее между тем и этим - разные каталоги в пределах одного домена.

Comment: Лучше будет третий вариант: прочесть статьи о факторах влияющих на скорость загрузки страниц, осознать всю бессмысленность подобных вопросов, и решать проблемы по мере их реального возникновения.

Comment: Поддомены и директории напрямую не влияют на скорость загрузки страниц, они влияют на индивидуальный комфорт при работе (одним приятнее простота и минимализм, другим - сложная многоуровневая иерархия). Поэтому, наплодить ли их, это вопрос не правильности, а личного желания... В общем и целом, совершать действия без причины - нерационально. Но если хочется намеренно, целенаправленно усложнить себе жизнь (добавить новых интересных проблем и порешать их), то почему бы и нет... нагородив сложную организацию размещения файлов, можно научиться конфигурировать серверы, например.

Comment: Говоря о статьях: https://web.dev/fast/